# Scala: GraphX: error: class Array takes type parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am trying to build an Edge RDD for GraphX. I am reading a csv file and converting to DataFrame Then trying to convert to an Edge RDD:

```
val staticDataFrame = spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  option("inferSchema", true).
  csv("/projects/pdw/aiw_test/aiw/haris/Customers_DDSW-withDN$.csv")

val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[(VertexId, VertexId, String)]]  = 
  staticDataFrame.select(
    "dealer_customer_number",
    "parent_dealer_cust_number",
    "dealer_code"
  ).map{ (row: Array) => 
    Edge((
      row.getAs[Long]("dealer_customer_number"), 
      row.getAs[Long]("parent_dealer_cust_number"),
      row("dealer_code")
    ))
  }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
<console>:81: error: class Array takes type parameters
       val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[(VertexId, VertexId, String)]]  = staticDataFrame.select("dealer_customer_number", "parent_dealer_cust_number", "dealer_code").map((row: Array) => Edge((row.getAs[Long]("dealer_customer_number"), row.getAs[Long]("parent_dealer_cust_number"), row("dealer_code"))))
                                                                                                                                                                      ^
```

The result for

```
staticDataFrame.select("dealer_customer_number", "parent_dealer_cust_number", "dealer_code").take(1)
```

is

```
res3: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([0000101,null,B110])
```

Comment: could you please re-run the compilation on indented code? The monstrous line is completely unreadable also in the error message, but I'm not sure how to fix that... Use the gray `edit` button.

Comment: Okay ty. I will re-run the code.

Comment: Same error after running indented code:(

Comment: Of course it's the same error. But now the line number is actually meaningful, because it does not point to the gargantuan single-line query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Array` takes type parameters, so you would have to write `Array[Something]`. But this is probably not what you want anyway.

The dataframe is a `Dataset[Row]`, not a `Dataset[Array[_]]`, therefore you have to change

```
.map{ (row: Array) =>
```

to

```
.map{ (row: Row) =>
```

Or just omit the typing completely (it should be inferred):

```
.map{ row =>
```

Comment: Thank you for the right answer! I am able to make the code work with a few changes; as a new Scala learner I would appreciate it if you could explain how adding { instead of ( after map changes the context of the map function. Thank you!

Comment: @HarisIrshad In this particular example, the kind of used parentheses shouldn't change anything at all, I've used `{}` instead of `()` because that's my personal preference for longer `map`-clauses with lambdas that declare parameters explicitly. I do this because it's easier to change such a declaration to a pattern matching `{ case (...) => }`, which *does* require `{}` instead of `()`. So, it's essentially just a strategy to keep the code a tiny bit more modifiable. It's not essential for your problem. The type of `row` was what caused the error.